# Ionic 5: Toast button dismisses the toast despite its role isn't set to 'cancel'

Tags: ionic-framework, toast, ionic5

According to the documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast :

> Dismissing The toast can be dismissed automatically after a specific
> amount of time by passing the number of milliseconds to display it in
> the duration of the toast options. If a button with a role of "cancel"
> is added, then that button will dismiss the toast. To dismiss the
> toast after creation, call the dismiss() method on the instance.

But in the following code (from the same doc) both the CLOSE and FAVORITE buttons lead to the dismiss of the toast (and of course the call of toast.onDidDismiss()). But Only the CLOSE one has the role 'cancel'.
I would like to have a button and perform an action without closing the Toast, am I missing something ?

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'toast-example',
  templateUrl: 'toast-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toast-example.css'],
})
export class ToastExample {

  constructor(public toastController: ToastController) {}

  async presentToast() {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      message: 'Your settings have been saved.',
      duration: 2000
    });
    toast.present();
  }

  async presentToastWithOptions() {
    const toast = await this.toastController.create({
      header: 'Toast header',
      message: 'Click to Close',
      position: 'top',
      buttons: [
        {
          side: 'start',
          icon: 'star',
          text: 'Favorite',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Favorite clicked');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Done',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    await toast.present();
    const { role } = await toast.onDidDismiss();
    console.log('onDidDismiss resolved with role', role);
  }
}
```

Comment: please try alertControl instead of 'toastController'. and you can set 'backdropDismiss:false' to not closing alert

Comment: thanks for the tip, I finally stick to the toastController for now, since I reviewed the requirements for this project. This being said, I really would like to know if this is an ionic issue ? If so, I'll report it to the team...

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `role` to something other than `null` or `'cancel'`, and returning `false` on the handler() should do what you need.

Example:

```js
//...
buttons: [
{
  icon: "copy-outline",
  role: "copy",
  handler: () => {
    console.log("copied!");
    return false;
  }
}]
//...
```